# spring mvc and context from jar inside lib

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have one maven project which is generating jar file. This is spring project so it has application context and included when generated jar file.

Now I have another web app which had dependency on above jar project. All I need to do is load  the application context from jar file which is being included in war file's lib folder.

Is this something can be done? If yes then please explain me with some sample if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since that JAR file is in the WEB-INF/lib of your web app, that means it's in the CLASSPATH.  Use the Spring context loader listener in your web.xml to load your Spring application context XML from the `classpath:`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try to use listener and see how it come up.